# Running Service In Background

Tags: android

Am developing an application in which i added licensing. My app works fine for jelly bean 4.1 not for jelly bean 4.2 and above. When i send message from another mobile to activate the licensing the app is not fetching the message in jelly bean 4.2 and above but it works fine in 4.1. Now i run my app in android device using debugger it showing the following errors. please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

this my logcat error:

```
04-08 10:12:17.201: I/LOG(15378): JJ/data/data/com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm/files
04-08 10:12:17.202: I/s(15378): File decryptted: 
04-08 10:12:17.202: I/File(15378): File contents: 
04-08 10:12:17.203: I/s(15378): File decryptted: 
04-08 10:12:17.203: I/File(15378): File contents: 
04-08 10:12:17.203: I/log(15378): mainclassfalse
04-08 10:12:17.210: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15378): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-08 10:12:17.210: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15378): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378): Activity com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity$1@421e1de8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity$1@421e1de8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:805)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1551)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1531)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1525)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at com.commonsware.android.syssvc.alarm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-08 10:12:17.220: E/ActivityThread(15378):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 10:12:17.235: I/log(15378): 111111111111111111111111111111z111111111111111
```

04-08 10:12:17.254: I/log(15378): 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in logs, you've forgotten to unregister broadcast receiver. Try to add code `unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);` in MainActivity's `onStop()` or `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` methods.

If you are already unregistering receiver, try to do it earlier. For example, if you're unregistring it in `onDestroy()` method, then move it to `onStop()`. Or if you are unregistring it in `onStop()` then move it to `onPause()`

Comment: I used only onDestroy method.

Comment: then try to move this code to onPause() or onStop() method, bacause there is no 100% guarantee, that you onDestroy() method will be called. But onPause() is called 100% every time.

Comment: am using onDestroy method in AppService file not in MainActivity so please help me out

Comment: and where do you register it?

Comment: Hav registered in onDestroy method in AppService.java class

Comment: do you register and unregister it in onDestroy() method?

Comment: Hi team again am getting error only in samsung devices so help me.

Comment: Its working in all android device except samsung devices i dont why its happening like this help me out to come out from this problem.

Comment: create another topic and post your log